# Attach event not working when click on child

Tags: javascript

I have some dynamically added elements. I want to attach 'click' event on a specific class. But the problem is if I click on the child element it's not working. Here is my dynamically added elements.

```
<div id="steps">    
    <div class="step">
        <a class="btn step-del">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16"><path d="M12.277 3.763a.9.9 0 010 1.273L9.293 8.018l2.984 2.986a.9.9 0 01-1.273 1.272L8.02 9.291l-2.984 2.985a.9.9 0 01-1.273-1.272l2.984-2.986-2.984-2.982a.9.9 0 011.273-1.273L8.02 6.745l2.984-2.982a.9.9 0 011.273 0z"></path></svg>
        </a>

        Step 1
    </div>

    <div class="step">
        <a class="btn step-del">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16"><path d="M12.277 3.763a.9.9 0 010 1.273L9.293 8.018l2.984 2.986a.9.9 0 01-1.273 1.272L8.02 9.291l-2.984 2.985a.9.9 0 01-1.273-1.272l2.984-2.986-2.984-2.982a.9.9 0 011.273-1.273L8.02 6.745l2.984-2.982a.9.9 0 011.273 0z"></path></svg>
        </a>

        Step 2
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
    document.body.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {

        if ( evt.target.classList.contains("step-del") ) {
            alert(this)
        }
    }, false);
```

Comment: `if(evt.target.closest(".step-del"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the target is a child element of the "step-del", so you need to check with `closest`, which will search for the parent elements if any of them has "step-del" class.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
        const del = evt.target.closest(".step-del")
        if (del) {
            alert(del)
        }
    }, false);
```

```html
<div id="steps">    
    <div class="step">
        <a class="btn step-del">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16"><path d="M12.277 3.763a.9.9 0 010 1.273L9.293 8.018l2.984 2.986a.9.9 0 01-1.273 1.272L8.02 9.291l-2.984 2.985a.9.9 0 01-1.273-1.272l2.984-2.986-2.984-2.982a.9.9 0 011.273-1.273L8.02 6.745l2.984-2.982a.9.9 0 011.273 0z"></path></svg>
        </a>

        Step 1
    </div>

    <div class="step">
        <a class="btn step-del">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16"><path d="M12.277 3.763a.9.9 0 010 1.273L9.293 8.018l2.984 2.986a.9.9 0 01-1.273 1.272L8.02 9.291l-2.984 2.985a.9.9 0 01-1.273-1.272l2.984-2.986-2.984-2.982a.9.9 0 011.273-1.273L8.02 6.745l2.984-2.982a.9.9 0 011.273 0z"></path></svg>
        </a>

        Step 2
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Let me check

Answer (score 1):

`evt.target` is what you click on. You are clicking on a child so it is not going to trigger on a parent. So you would need to look to see if what is clicked on is the element or is a child of that element. You can do that with `.closest()`

```js
const stepDelElem = evt.target.closest(".step-del");
if (stepDelElem) {
  console.log('here');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`<svg>` is a different creature than normal HTML tags. A simple solution is to prevent any mouse events to interact with the `<svg>` by adding the following to CSS:

```css
svg {
  pointer-events: none
}
```

The other changes are just recommendations.

```js
document.getElementById('steps').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  if (evt.target.matches(".step-del")) {
    console.log(evt.target.className);
  }
}, false);
```

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: max-content;
  border: 1px solid red
}

svg {
  pointer-events: none
}
```

```html
<div id="steps">
  <div class="step">
    <a class="btn step-del">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16"><path d="M12.277 3.763a.9.9 0 010 1.273L9.293 8.018l2.984 2.986a.9.9 0 01-1.273 1.272L8.02 9.291l-2.984 2.985a.9.9 0 01-1.273-1.272l2.984-2.986-2.984-2.982a.9.9 0 011.273-1.273L8.02 6.745l2.984-2.982a.9.9 0 011.273 0z"></path></svg>Step
      1
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="step">
    <a class="btn step-del">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16"><path d="M12.277 3.763a.9.9 0 010 1.273L9.293 8.018l2.984 2.986a.9.9 0 01-1.273 1.272L8.02 9.291l-2.984 2.985a.9.9 0 01-1.273-1.272l2.984-2.986-2.984-2.982a.9.9 0 011.273-1.273L8.02 6.745l2.984-2.982a.9.9 0 011.273 0z"></path></svg>Step
      2
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```